# Influxdb-python: error inserting utf8 data

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, influxdb

I want to insert some data from mysql to influxDB. The data in sql are utf-8 encoded and i am using python 2.6.6 on vagrant.

```
$] python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
```

Here is the structure of table and sample data of mysql.

```
mysql> show create table countries;
-----------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table         |
+-----------+----------------------+
| countries | CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+----------------------------------+

mysql> select id,name from countries;
+------+----------------------------------+
| id   | name                             |
+------+----------------------------------+
|   11 | Afghanistan                      |
|   12 | Åland Islands                    |
|   13 | Albania                          |
|   14 | Côte d’Ivoire                    |
+------+----------------------------------+
```

Some countries contains special character. I am using below python code to fetch data from mysql and the insert into influxDB.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb
import json
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","platform" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute("SELECT id,name from countries")

# Fetch a all row using fetchall() method.
data = cursor.fetchall()

json_body = []

for id,name in data:
 print id,name
 json_1 = {
    "measurement": "cpu_load_short",
    "tags": {
        "host": "server01",
        "region": "us-west"
    },
    "time": id,
    "fields": {
        "value": name.decode('utf8') // ERROR
    }
 }
 #json_1 = json.dumps(json_1).encode('utf8')
 json_body.append(json_1)

#json_body = json.dumps(json_body, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')

client = InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', 'example')

client.create_database('example')

client.write_points(json_body)

result = client.query('select * from cpu_load_short;')

print("Result: {0}".format(result))

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

I am getting error while decoding data:

```
$] python test.py
11 Afghanistan
12 Åland Islands
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    "value": name.decode('utf8')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

If i remove decoding from  name:

```
"fields": {
        "value": name
    }
```

I still get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 43, in <module>
    client.write_points(json_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 391, in write_points
    tags=tags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 436, in _write_points
    expected_response_code=204
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 276, in write
    data=make_lines(data, precision).encode('utf-8'),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/influxdb/line_protocol.py", line 119, in make_lines
    value = _escape_value(point['fields'][field_key])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/influxdb/line_protocol.py", line 53, in _escape_value
    value = _get_unicode(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/influxdb/line_protocol.py", line 73, in _get_unicode
    return data.decode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Any solution of this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unidecode` to convert unicode data to ASCII text.

```
import unidecode
name = unidecode.unidecode_expect_nonascii(name)
```

Comment: This will insert `Aland Islands` instead of `Åland Islands`. I want to keep it same way.

Comment: also you can try setting the collation of database in mysql as `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: `Côte d’Ivoire` will become `Cote dIvoire`. This doesn't serve my purpose.

Comment: Try for different  collation in mysql - `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Also have you included this at start of your python code                     `#!/usr/bin/python
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Answer (score 0):

You should not do any decoding/encoding.

When connecting to MySQL, specify utf8.

[*Other Python-MySQL notes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python)